# converge in $\mu$ almost everywhere

Tags: real-analysis, limits, measure-theory, convergence-divergence, integral-inequality

Let $(X, \mathcal{E}, \mu ) $ be a measurespace. Let $(f_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$, $f$, $(g_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ and $g$ $\in \mathcal{M}(\mathcal{E})$. Let $\alpha, \beta \in \mathbb{R}$. Show, if:

$f_n \rightarrow f$ $\mu$-a.e and $g_n \rightarrow g$ $\mu$-a.e $\hspace{1mm}$ then: $\hspace{1mm}$  $\alpha f_n + \beta g_n \rightarrow \alpha f + \beta g$ $\mu$-a.e..

I dont want a solution for this exercise, but just some help or a hint. My idea is showing this $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \int_X |(\alpha f_n + \beta g_n) - (\alpha f + \beta g)| <\infty $. But I'm stuck, and I don't know how to prove this.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: you are thinking way to hard. It is almost immediate  from definition. Recall that convergence a.e = convergence outside a set of measure zero. So outside of a set of measure zero $f_n\rightarrow f$ and outside another set of measure zero $g_n\rightarrow g$....

Comment: But how can I be sure that $\beta f_n \rightarrow \beta f$ outside a set of $A$, where $\mu(A) = 0$? I only know $f_n \rightarrow f$ outside a set of $A$, where $\mu(A) = 0$

Comment: You should read the definition of convergence a.e. again, do you understand why $f_n\rightarrow f$ implies $\alpha f_n\rightarrow \alpha f$ when the "a.e" is being removed?

Comment: I know if $f_n \rightarrow f$ without "a.e", then $f_n$ converges pointwise to $f$ except countable many points? Am I wrong?

Comment: I do understand why $f_n \rightarrow f$  without "a.e". But this is "normal" convergence?

Comment: You are wrong, $f_n\rightarrow f$ usually means that $f_n$ convergence pointwise to $f$. Hence for every $x$ you have a "normal" convergence $f_n(x)\rightarrow f(x)$. If you add 'a.e' then $f_n\rightarrow f$ pointwise only for all $x\in X$ outside of a set of measure zero.

Comment: Please add a definition for $f_n\rightarrow f$ a.e, and I will write a full detailed answer for you.

Comment: Thank you. In my book: $f_n$ convergeres to $f$ almost everwhere if $\mu(\{x\in X: lim_{n \rightarrow \infty } f_n = f\}^c ) = 0$. Which is the same you wrote.

Comment: Then: $\{x\in X: lim_{n \rightarrow \infty } f_n = f\}$ must be a null-set. I noticed that I said something nonsense before. I know if $f_n \rightarrow f$ without "a.e", then $f_n$ converges pointwise to  $f$ in every $x \in X$

Answer (score 1):

By assumption and your definition we have

$A=\{x\in X: \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} f_n(x)\not=f(x)\}$

$B=\{x\in X: \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} g_n(x)\not=g(x)\}$

Are sets of measure zero. For all $x\not\in A$ we have $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} f_n(x) = f(x)$ and so $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \alpha f_n(x)=\alpha f(x)$. The same with $g$ and $x\not\in B$.

Now let $C=A\cup B$ we have for all $x\not\in A$ that both $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \alpha f_n(x)=\alpha f(x)$ and $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \alpha g_n(x)=\alpha g(x)$ which implies that $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \alpha f_n+\beta g_n(x)=\alpha f(x)+\beta g(x)$.

Now $\mu(C)\leq \mu(A)+\mu(B)=0+0=0$. Hence by definition $\{x\in X:\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \alpha f_n+\beta g_n(x)\not =\alpha f(x)+\beta g(x)\}$ is a subset of $C$ which is of measure zero and so it is also of measure zero.

Comment: Yanko, what if we change inequalities to equalities? I guess there's a problem if $\mu(X)=\infty$?